# How to remove microsoft logo from Azure AD login page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have configured application in Azure AD and also added custom branding as per guidelines [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-add-company-branding/) 
we have paid for the premium license so we can do the custom branding on login page. However on the login page we still see Microsoft Logo at the bottom of the page
[image]

How do I remove it?